# Foreach Data not reflected to UI with Knouckout Js Object Obserable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Below is the view modal where I am getting the ajax response and load to the obserable value.

```
var userManagementVM = {
    responseSetUpData: ko.observable({
        userList: ko.observable(),
        userListViewModel: ko.observableArray(),
        MeetingId: ko.observable(),
        MeetingTypeId: ko.observable(),
        MeetingType: ko.observable()
    }),
     SetListOfUserInRoles: function () {
        var self = this;
        var ajaxUrl = ApplicationRootUrl("UserRoleManagement", "UserManagement");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                self.responseSetUpData(data);
                console.log(self.responseSetUpData())
            },
            error: function (err) {

            }
        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(userManagementVM, document.getElementById("rightdash-container"));
    userManagementVM.SetListOfUserInRoles();
});
```

The response from the ajax is successfully loaded to the obserable value. Below is the output of the console

[image: response]

HTML code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Users</th>
            <th scope="col">Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: responseSetUpData.userListViewModel">
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: SelectedUser"><span data-bind="text: $data.FirstName"></span></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $data.Roles,optionsText: 'Name',value: $data.SelectedRoleId,optionsCaption: '-- Select Role --'"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The value is not bind to the UI.

Comment: `self.responseSetUpData(data)` will remove the observable properties within and turn them into regular javascript key-value pairs sent from the server in data. You can use [`ko.mapping plugin`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the observable - `responseSetUpData()` in the binding:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: responseSetUpData().userListViewModel">
```

Otherwise you are trying to get `userListViewModel` from the observable function object :-)